# How can I evenly space social icons to the right with angular material and flex?

Tags: angular-material, angular-flex-layout

my goal is 3 boxes: menu icon all the way to the left, site name/log in the center, and group of social icons to the top right.  However it looks like this:
[image]

header.component.html:

```
<mat-toolbar class="nav" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" color="primary">
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="mainMenu">
  <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-menu #mainMenu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/">
    <mat-icon color="accent">home</mat-icon>
    <span>Home</span>
  </button>
.... more buttons...
</mat-menu>
<span>site name</span>
<div class="icons-box">
  <button mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon>facebook</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <button mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon>instagram</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <button mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon>tiktok</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <button mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon>whatsapp</mat-icon>
  </button>  
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="languageMenu">
  <mat-icon svgIcon="{{getFlagRef()}}"></mat-icon>
  <mat-icon>arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-menu #languageMenu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let item of languageData" (click)="selectLang(item.lang)">
    <mat-icon svgIcon="{{item.flagRef}}"></mat-icon>
    <span>{{item.name}}</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item>
      <mat-icon svgIcon="../../assets/flags/us.svg"></mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-menu>
</div>
```

Here is the scss:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
mat-card {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  max-width: 700px;
}
.title-card-right {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}
.nav {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0; /* required */
}
.icons-box {
  min-width: 200px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

I tried to put the group of icons in their own div thinking flex layout would consider them a single "box" but for some reason they're on top of eachother.  Have tried setting min width, and flex grow to 1, but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `<mat-icon>instagram</mat-icon>` is not a valid mat-icon name - I'm not sure if there is a valid name for Instagram or if you'll have to use an svg.

Everything else looks good as far as flexboxes!